# Is there a way to export keyframe data from After Effects to flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, keyframe, after-effects

I used a motion tracker in After effects to trace the path of an object. I would like to take the X and Y data and export it to an object in flash. I had hoped there was a quick and easy way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found this post about doing this

http://oliverwolfson.com/extracting-raw-key-frame-data/

he uses a shell script, I'm going to try and replicate this using PHP. If I have any luck, I'll post it online for folks to use.